# Getting trouble to show birthday reminder

Tags: java, android, sqlite, notifications, alarmmanager

My application contains a SQLite database to store a person's information.
I store birthday as a long value. I want to show notification if someone has birthday today in the saved list. I am retrieving the long birthday value, setting it to a calendar and comparing it with current calendar month and day. But the problem is if someone has birthday matching with current day the the notification arises but shows that it is the birthday of the last person in the list whatever be the birthday of the last person. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here are the codes

```
calendar_now = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar_now.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int month_now = calendar_now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day_now = calendar_now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    //Set a specific time to the calendar
    calendar_now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
    calendar_now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar_now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    personArrayList = dbHelper.getPerson();

    birth_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    for (Person p : personArrayList) {

        name = p.getName(); //Get the person's name
        mobile = p.getMobile();
        byte_image = p.getByteImage();
        position = personArrayList.indexOf(p);
        DoB = p.getDateOfBirth();
        birth_calendar.setTimeInMillis(DoB);
        int birth_month = birth_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int birthday = birth_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        if ((birth_month == month_now) && (birthday == day_now)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar_now.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No birthday today", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        birth_calendar.clear();

    }
```

NotificationReceiver.java

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //Open PersonDetailsActivity on notification click
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, PersonDetailsActivity.class);
    //Pass the values through intent to PersonDetailsActivity
    resultIntent.putExtra("name", MainActivity.name);
    resultIntent.putExtra("mobile", MainActivity.mobile);
    resultIntent.putExtra("DoB", MainActivity.DoB);
    resultIntent.putExtra("image", MainActivity.byte_image);
    resultIntent.putExtra("position", MainActivity.position);

    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100,
            resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder)
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle("Birthday reminder")
                    .setContentText("It is " +MainActivity.name+ "'s birthday today, " +
                            "wish him/her \"Happy birthday!!\"")
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{250, 250, 250, 250})
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ((birth_month == month_now) && (birthday == day_now)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context , DocumentSubFolder.class);
            intent.putExtra("name" , name);
            intent.putExtra("mobile" , mobile);
            intent.putExtra("Dob" , DoB);
            intent.putExtra("image" , byte_image);
            intent.putExtra("position" , position);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar_now.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
```

NotificationReceiver.java

```
resultIntent.putExtra("name", intent.getStringExtra("name));
    resultIntent.putExtra("mobile", intent.getStringExtra("mobile));
    resultIntent.putExtra("DoB", intent.getStringExtra("Dob));
    resultIntent.putExtra("image", intent.getStringExtra("image));
    resultIntent.putExtra("position", intent.getStringExtra("position));
```

Replace your code with this.

Comment: Ohh man, you are really boss @Nirmal Prajapat. Thank a lot. It is working properly now. What does this line do 'Intent intent = new Intent(context , DocumentSubFolder.class);' I think I don't need it. Is it a sample for 'Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);'? If more than one person have same birthday in the list, only last person's birthday is notified. How can I show notification for each person?

Comment: In your Person list, just check if there is any duplicate entry, if yes then add some miliseconds in calendar_now.getTimeInMillis() of this line alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar_now.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent); . atleast add 5000 miliseconds.